# How to vertical align an anchor inside li?

Tags: css

I want to create a menu with a 'button' (anchor) in the last `<li>`.

So far so good, but when I want to create the button, I can't get it to vertical center it.

Here is [a live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wksfdszu/).

```css
nav
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  
  background-color:blue;
}

ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
}

li
{
    height: 60px;
   color: #000000;
  font-family: $font-family-semi-bold;
  float:left;
    background-color:green;
    line-height:60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.vertical
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello World1</li>
    <li>Hello World2</li>
    <li>Hello World3</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="vertical">
        Vertical align this!
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to `.vertical`.

code updated https://jsfiddle.net/wksfdszu/1/

Comment: Of course, stupid. I tried vertical-align: CENTER. Thanks man! Will accept your answer in 10 minutes (can't accept now)

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to vertically center the `<a>` tag as well as the text inside of it, you can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

**CSS**

```
.vertical
{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wksfdszu/2/)**

```css
nav
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  
  background-color:blue;
}

ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
}

li
{
    height: 60px;
    color: #000000;
        font-family: $font-family-semi-bold;
        float:left;
    background-color:green;
    line-height:60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.vertical
{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello World1</li>
    <li>Hello World2</li>
    <li>Hello World3</li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="vertical">
        Vertical align this!
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertical-align as @tatty say is ok but you also need to adjust the height of the element:

```
.vertical
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  background-color:red;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Otherwise it wil not be on the same line with your other elements